# Whats the best way to publish and promote an app by myself?

Tags: marketing, publishing

My first little casual-action android game is nearly finished. Its my first one and i dont expect any sucess. But nevertheless i want to try to publish and market it by myself.

But what can i do without any bugdet? How do i attract and reach people ? Are there any tricks ? How did you published and promoted your first app/game ? And what is your experience with self publishing/marketing ?

Comment: Self publishing for mobile devices is literally just throwing money at apple/google and uploading an apk/whatever ios games came as

Comment: Marking as a duplicate of a closed question. Really?